# Magento 2.2 - Notice: Undefined index: Magento\Integration\Model\IntegrationService

Tags: magento2, third-party-module

I am trying to install a module I've created on Magento 2.1 to Magento 2.2 but when I compile it, it give the following error:

> Notice: Undefined index: Magento\Integration\Model\IntegrationService
>   in vendor/magento/framework/Interception/PluginList/PluginList.php on
>   line 250

I really don't know what could cause the issue. The issue is that Magento tries to get the following:

`$this->_inherited['Magento\Integration\Model\IntegrationService']['webapiIntegrationService']['instance']`

The problem is that _inherited array doesn't have 'Magento\Integration\Model\IntegrationService' key in it.

I believe that this is caused by my module at some stage but I don't see where.

Developer mode and using `bin/magento setup:upgrade -vvv` doesn't help.

Does anyone know what could cause the issue or eventually could anyone give me direction on where to check?

Comment: try to clean `[ROOT]/generated` and `var`

Comment: thanks for the tip, but this is something that I've already tried. I actually tried on two different machines to verify if it wasn't caused by varnish among other things...

Comment: @user3245246 did you solve it?

Comment: did you ever solve this? I have this issue with a plugin that calls beforeDispatch on FrontController